# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException from EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I'm in the process of moving a simple Kafka consumer application out of an existing framework and feel like spring-cloud-stream is an easy way to do that. I used Initializr to bootstrap the app, which is now using Spring-Boot v1.3.3 and Spring-Cloud-Stream v1.0.0-RC1. The application is extremely simple, all it has to do is pick a message from Kafka, deserialize the JSON encoded object and pass it on to our existing library. To get started I just used the LogSink example, since eventually I won't do much else (just deserialize and pass object to a different method).

It all works great: It connects to Kafka, receives the message and passes it (as byte[]) to my sink. However, EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter logs a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
2016-04-11 10:06:50.287 ERROR 11464 --- [pool-1-thread-1] fkaMessageChannelBinder$ReceivingHandler : Could not convert message: 7B2267656E65726174696F6E223A3 [...]
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2009
    at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:373) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:413) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.oldExtractHeaders(EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.RC1.jar:1.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.extractHeaders(EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.RC1.jar:1.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ReceivingHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:583) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-1.0.0.RC1.jar:1.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) [spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:69) [spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:63) [spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) [spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105) [spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:43) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$AutoAcknowledgingChannelForwardingMessageListener.doOnMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:171) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.AbstractDecodingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractDecodingMessageListener.java:50) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.QueueingMessageListenerInvoker$KafkaMessageDispatchingSubscriber.onNext(QueueingMessageListenerInvoker.java:221) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.QueueingMessageListenerInvoker$KafkaMessageDispatchingSubscriber.onNext(QueueingMessageListenerInvoker.java:209) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at reactor.core.processor.util.RingBufferSubscriberUtils.route(RingBufferSubscriberUtils.java:67) [reactor-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at reactor.core.processor.RingBufferProcessor$BatchSignalProcessor.run(RingBufferProcessor.java:789) [reactor-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/209 seems to indicate the problem is missing Kafka headers, which is true, there aren't any. But the solution mentioned there is to add

```
spring.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.mode=raw
```

to my application configuration. Unfortunately that did not work for me. Also, STS actually has auto-completion for the respective properties and it suggested

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.mode=raw
```

Neither of the 2 (separately or combined) made any difference, the exception is still being logged.

I have used Spring for years, but this would be my first Spring-Boot/Spring-Cloud application.

Here's the application code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UpdateApplication {
    private static Logger logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UpdateApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UpdateApplication.class, args);
    }

    @EnableBinding(Sink.class)
    public static class UpdateHandler {

        @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
        //@ServiceActivator(inputChannel=Sink.INPUT)
        public void loggerSink(Object payload) {
            logger.info("Received: " + payload);
        }        
    }
}
```

I tried both, @ServiceActivator as well as @StreamListener annotation, which in this case does not seem to make a difference.

My application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.binder=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=updates
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=update-client
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=brokerName
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=zookeeperName
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.mode=raw
```

Any help to get rid of this error would be appreciated.

As a side note: Since I just started experimenting with spring-cloud-stream I added

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.updates.consumer.resetOffsets=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.updates.consumer.startOffset=earlist
```

to the configuration to avoid having to send new messages every time I restart, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `RC` that option has been moved to the `.consumer.` configuration option.

So, right now you have to do like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.mode=raw
```

See more info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_consumer_properties).

Comment: Hi - this is the correct version, the RC2 documentation still used the wrong property name. http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_consumer_properties (i.e. `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw`)

Comment: Ah, thank you, @MariusBogoevici, this works. Also, I was under the impression that <channelName> in the documentation refers to the actual destination (in my case "update"), while it should be "input". Just out of curiosity: spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.resetOffsets=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.startOffset=earlist
should read from the beginning, no? That still doesn't work, but I don't really need it right now.

Comment: That's right - the key is the channel name not the value of `destination` - this allows you to keep your logical configuration while being able to just override the destination at runtime for instance.

Comment: Hi Volker - the correct paths are `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.resetOffsets=true` and  `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.startOffset=earliest` - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_consumer_properties

Comment: @MariusBogoevici, makes sense. Alright, so to solve my problem I had to add
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw
and since the starter package pulls RC1 overwrite the POM with            org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka:1.0.0.RC2
        org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:1.0.0.RC2
        org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:1.0.0.RC2
        org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-codec:1.0.0.RC2

Answer (score 0):

`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw`

is working for version 1.1.0.RELEASE.